# Custom log_format - Nginx Proxy Manager

Tags: nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

Does anyone know how to configure custom Nginx Proxy Manager logs ? I need to make a json log_format for my promtail to finaly been able to make a grafana dashboard with json custom format log. (I've made this on "normal" Nginx before and it work great and now I have to make this on Nginx Proxy Manager..)

Bellow is my current data folder for Nginx Proxy Manager :

```
data/nginx/
├── dead_host
├── default_host
│   └── site.conf
├── default_www
├── proxy_host
│   └── 1.conf
├── redirection_host
├── stream
└── temp
```

And that's the format that I wanna put on my log :

```
log_format json_analytics escape=json '{'
      '"time_local": "$time_local", '
      '"remote_addr": "$remote_addr", '
      '"request_uri": "$request_uri", '
      '"status": "$status", '
      '"http_referer": "$httpReferer", '
      '"http_user_agent": "$httpAgent", '
      '"server_name": "$server_name", '
      '"request_time": "$request_time", '
      '"geoip2_data_country_code": "$geoip2_data_country_code", '
      '"geoip2_data_country_name": "$geoip2_data_country_name", '
      '"geoip2_data_city_name": "$geoip2_data_city_name", '
      '"geoip2_data_postal_code": "$geoip2_data_postal_code", '
      '"geoip2_data_latitude": "$geoip2_data_latitude", '
      '"geoip2_data_longitude": "$geoip2_data_longitude", '
      '"geoip2_data_state_name": "$geoip2_data_state_name", '
      '"geoip2_data_state_code": "$geoip2_data_state_code"'
      '}';
```

I've been trying to do this for a while, but I don't know how to do it and I haven't found a place to do it in WebUI.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

was just looking into this myself.
NPM has a directory called /data/nginx/custom

You can place your customizations in there, see for details: https://zachthesplunker.com/splunk-the-nginx-proxy-manager/

Hope this helps,

Gerrit

Comment: However, the geoip does not come OOB I think, but maybe this helps.